Using Homebrew to switch PHP versions on MacOS not working
I'm having a terrible time switching my php versions over. I've installed php using homebrew, and I also have Laravel Valet set up on my machine.
If I run php -v I get the following output:
PHP 8.1.29
If I run which php, I get the following output:
/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.1/bin/php
If I run brew list --versions php, I get the following output:
php 8.3.10
Notice that only 8.3 is listed here, despite having 8.1, 8.2, and 8.3 installed, and that system reports my current php version in use is 8.1.29.
If I navigate to opt/homebrew/etc/php, I can see the following directories:
8.1
8.2
8.3

So those php versions do exist.
If I try to change php versions by using the following commands:
brew unlink php@8.1
brew link php@8.2

Then run php -v, it still shows this output:
PHP 8.1.29
Really struggling to understand what's going on. I clearly have 8.1 and 8.2 installed. PHP 8.1 is the version that's in use. Yet for some reason I just can't change to 8.2.
Note: I've also ran export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.2/bin:$PATH" to add it to my environment variables.

Have you checked your $PATH?  It sounds like 8.1 is still in the path, and appears before any others?

@Don'tPanic yep this was it. I'm using php monitor as well, so maybe that caused some issues. I had to manually update the .zshrc file, although I'm not sure why as usually when I change php versions it works seemlessly.

For anyone else that comes across this issue, check your $PATH! Here's what I did: 1. nano ~/.zshrc 2. check path variables and update to the version you want. 3. source ~/.zshrc 4. php -v to check version has switched successfully.
